# while user inactivity of 2mins getting info "This request caused a new process to be started for your application"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I deployed my application on GAE using java and GWT. when i login to my app using my app id sample.sampleappId.appspot.com. In my application there is lots of form when i filling the form like customer registration then if i filled half of form and i stop filling the form and after 2, 3 minutes i continue remaining form filling then i click on save button then in logger i am getting Info like

"This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."

I am facing this lots of time.
   Why GAE throwing this info.

My appengine-web.xml:-

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>sampleappId</application>
  <version>25</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <instance-class>F4_1G</instance-class>


  <!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />

    <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
    <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
  </static-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

any solution?
any help?

Answer (score 0):

These are perfectly normal INFO level logs (not WARNING or ERROR levels) from the GAE infra, indicating that the respective request triggered lauching of a new GAE Instance.

You can read more about launcing of new instances in the [Scaling dynamic instances doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/scaling#scaling_dynamic_instances).

It's also possible that the previous instance life was cut short for various possible reasons. Check you app's logs in the developer console to see if it's indeed the case and, if so, get details. These you may want/need to address.

I just realized another possibility when I saw your other question [How to call my app url from google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044339/how-to-call-my-app-url-from-google-app-engine?lq=1).

If your app makes requests to itself directly from within request handlers you can create infinite recursion loops, forcing GAE to spawn a new instance for each such request. Nothing may show up in the logs since GAE logs a request only *after* it serves it (at least in the python sandbox). Unless you specifically create logs before making the recursive calls. Eventually the instances blocked waiting for responses (which will never come due to the infinite recursion) will be killed as they'll exceed the request deadline.

Comment: Thanks for your response but how to avoid this because of this i always make refresh my url then continue the work

Comment: because of this my application is not working fine so how can i fix this

Comment: It's not **because of this** that the app doesn't work fine. You need to describe what "not working fine" means.

Comment: means if user accessing my app and he login to my app then if registering form then he stopped working and after 2 minutes he continue working then he must make refresh the url and login and then again start the registering form beginning

Comment: so how can i fix this

Comment: Apart from those info messages (which AFAIK you can't "fix") is your app functioning as expected (based on app behaviour + request logs, number/status of instances running and other info from the developer console)?

Comment: thanks for your response how can i use backends with automatic scaling

Comment: You might want to stay away from backends - they're deprecated: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/