# app engine warning in request log

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am write java application at the Google app engine. Something I got warning message from some request.

Here is warning message in deployment server

> This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Is there any problem for application or should I ignore that warning message?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34036513/4495081

Answer (score 0):

Just like Dan's link says, you can generally ignore those warnings. Basically it means that App Engine decided that you needed a new instance to handle the request. It can happen because your application has not been accessed for around 15 minutes, or there are too many requests for the current instances to handle in a timely manner, so App Engine spins up another instance to handle them.

You can get worried if you often see that message with this one:
[image: memory leak image]

But if it is only the warning, it is very normal and you can ignore it.